# google plus sign in and facebook login error after published

Tags: android, google-plus, facebook-sdk-4.0

After I published my app in the Google Play store, I can't sign into Google Plus and Facebook.

Both are giving an error. The Facebook error shows me the key hash doesn't match to any stored key hash, but I have declared true key hashes for both logins.

Please I really need help

Comment: Did U Shifted Your Project To Other Eclipse Or Studio When You Published it

Comment: Try to generate SHA-1 fingerprint and Key Hash using the key store you have used for Signing the APK.

Comment: You mean one more again do i need to generate it?

Comment: Actually I have generated signed apk file 2 times first when I was testing gplus sing in and facebook login and then when my app was ready I generated but For second time I generated existing key store path with same password correctly and then published it but both are giving error

Answer (score 1):

open play store and find SHA1 in app signing copy it to new finger print and download new certificate and copy it to app, then generate new apk and upload it

App signing certificate SHA1 fingerprint

play store an part App signing like this [image: pic]

Comment: check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53663789/9427138) for more details :

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my own question's issue 
so I have generated new Key hash and SHA-1 fingerprint using the existing key store that I have signed the APK before.

And I have reuploaded key hash with previous one in facebook developer console and SHA-1 fingerprint too in google developer console