# Google sign in not working after publishing in play store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I went through [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html), and as far as the process goes I did that.

[image]

But I when I installed the app from play store I am not able to sign in using the `google sign in` button.

I have used Firebase for google sign in. When I am clicking the sign in button the option to choose the account is coming but then it is not signing in or doing anything.

So where possibly am I going wrong?

Comment: Add release keystore SHA1, get new API keys for it, set them in AndroidManifest if needed, and compile with new google-services.json

Comment: @DimaRostopira I already included my project SHA keys in the Firebase account. What else is there and how to add in the Manifest?

Comment: in Manifest? Nothing, it's required only on some other API. Just get new google-services.json. And check GoogleApiClient init, maybe you use API key here directly

Comment: @DimaRostopira But I have already got the google-services.json from firebase after completing the process. Why to get a new one?

Comment: Because it contains API keys, which is different for debug and release

Comment: @DimaRostopira From where are saying me to get the json file? Firebase?

Comment: Yes, in Firebase Console press settings icon at the right of app name, choose project settings and you will see

Comment: @DimaRostopira Can you tell me how to get the release SHA1 key. I have created the .jks file but how to get the release sha1 key?

Comment: let's move discussion to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow

Comment: @DimaRostopira I can see the messages in the chat group but can't log in..

Comment: strange, anyway here is described how to get SHA https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en#release-cert Add this SHA in FirebaseConsole project, and get new .json

Comment: @DimaRostopira In my alias name and the key with `.jks` extension I have space in between. So its creating problem for me while generating.

Comment: in terminal space must be spicified as "\ ". Or just rename that file and avoid spaces in files/folders name

Comment: @DimaRostopira Thanks a lot. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860015/6366458 also worked.

Comment: tell me if it worked, so I will post it as answer

Comment: @DimaRostopira. Sure. Let me check.

Comment: @DimaRostopira It might take hours for google to publish the update. You should write the answer.

Comment: Why do you uploading? Build -> Build signed APK, then install that APK and test

Comment: @DimaRostopira Install as in the regular `Run` in android studio?

Comment: Nope, after build completed you will see popup with button "Show in file manager", choose it, transfer it to device and install manually

Comment: @DimaRostopira Okay doing.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

When you upload an apk to the play store then play store creates a new SHA1 key called "**App signing certificate**". You get that SHA1 and save in your console or firebase account (as you need).

New SHA1 will be found at **Released Management**->**App Sigining** on your play console.

[[image]]

Comment: @PrinkalKumar after uploading an apk to playstore, and adding SHA1 of App signing to firebase console with debug SHA1. Do I need to re-download the google-services.json file and publish the signed apk again?
Do reply.

Comment: @PankajLilan No , You added your SHA1 thats enough. But for better result  re-download and save .json file .So this will be used on next update of your app. Firebase only use your package name string from .json file and it will check all VALID SHA1 from its console itself. So if package name is same ,only SHA1 is different ,there is no need to re download google-serveice.json file again. Hope this will help

Comment: You saved my life. They should have a proper documentation regarding this. How did we miss this issue. This works perfectly. This answer should be mentioned as the correct answer!

Comment: Thank you.. For Gmail API auth2.0 signin certificate this will also work. we should NOT use upload certificate , but use signed certificate.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. But just where is this burried in the documentation??

Comment: works, but for release only. If I upload app in internal test track, it still breaks.

Comment: internal test track and release uses different keys. I got test track keys from `App Certificate` Section of internal test track, wasn't too hard to find. Sorry for posting a comment before trying to find the keys in play console

Comment: I know i am late but for Gmail API auth2.0, i used the App signing certificate in the Google API console and it works fine. But if i want to debug my app in android studio, it doesn't work. How do i do this ?

Comment: On latest version of Google Play, App signing key certificate is located under:
`Release -> Setup -> App Signing`

Comment: Now it is found under: Release -> Setup -> App Integrity -> App signing key certificate

Comment: in recent is there any update? i copy sha1 from app signing but it not working in play store download, but working on debug mode. thanks.

Comment: @SaiedIslamShuvo App siging is absolute and there is no change on this process. I recommend you check your SHA keys once again. It might be possible that you missplaced something.

Comment: @PrinkalKumar it works before  added firebase, after added firebase its not working, and don't wanna use firebase for google auth, i used firebase for fcm,  what can i do? thanks.

Comment: @SaiedIslamShuvo "What is not working" , could you please share more detail now.

Comment: @PrinkalKumar google sign in not working, it throw PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Comment: @SaiedIslamShuvo Try to add support email in the Settings -> General -> Public Settings. and check if it works.

Comment: @PrinkalKumar its not working, it works on debug mode, but I had putted app signing sha1 in google cloud console

Comment: "but I had putted app signing sha1 in google cloud console"  SHA1 should be on your firebase console

Answer (score 44):

The problem was created when Google Play App Signing was enabled for my app. Google Play App Signing changes the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint (from what is in my keystore) to their own SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.

**The fix:**

1. **Goto** https://play.google.com/apps/publish/
2. **Click** your application >> Release Management >> App Signing.

> You will see "App signing certificate" and "Upload certificate"

3. **Copy** the SHA-1 From "App Signing Certificate." (THE TOP ONE)
4. **Goto** https://console.firebase.google.com/
5. **Click** your application >> Settings [Gearbox Icon to the right of project overview] (top of the screen) >> Project Settings >> General [Tab] >> Add Fingerprint
6. **Paste** the SHA-1 App Signing Certificate. Save.

All fixed!

Answer (score 43):

**Update: Google changed behaviour of uploading APK, check answer below!**

Release APK and debug APK has different SHA1 and different API keys for google services. Both of them must be added in Firebase Console -> Project settings. Then download `google-services.json` from here, add it to project and recompile with release keystore using option "Build signed APK". That should work

Comment: @DimaRostopira Can you please explain me how to add "API Keys" for debug and release mode? i have created project in firebase console.

Comment: @Maulikpatel behaviour has changed, check answer below

Comment: I have also generated sha1 for release apk but still after publishing the app on play store google login not working,

Comment: @LovekushVishwakarma check answer below. You should also add SHA1 for key generated by Google Play Developer Console in **Released Management->App Sigining**

Comment: @DimaRostopira Please check my issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235295/google-signin-working-in-release-apk-but-not-on-play-store?noredirect=1#comment97203989_55235295, its a completely different scenario from here

Answer (score 17):

There are three types of SHA1 is required for an app lifecycle when you are using firebase

- **-debug SHA1**
- **-release SHA1**
- **-signing SHA1** (it getting from play store)

You need to add signing SHA1 to firebase after publish your application here i am attaching two screen shots please have a look . The red marked certificates is must be required, so copy it from playstore and paste it on firbase [image]

[image]

In firebase paste here

Comment: adding both SHA-1 certificates helped. Thanks

Comment: Not working. After following these steps. Does the fix happen immediately or we have to wait?

Comment: It will happen immediately

Answer (score 14):

In the **latest Google play** console 2022:

##### QUICK GUIDE:

`Application Play console` > `Setup` > `App Integrity`

**OR** 
Search `App Integrity` in application's Search box

##### DETAILED GUIDE:

**Step 1:** Go to https://play.google.com/console/u/3/developers and open your application's Dashboard

**Step 2:** On the left sidebar under **`Release`**, select **`Setup`**, then **`App Integrity`**.

**Optional:** You could also simply *search* `App Integrity` in the Search.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

### **Issue happens because**

1) when you create / publish an app through google play console, there is an option for enable Google Play App Signing. if you enable it will show

> Google Play App Signing is enabled for this app.

[image]

then your Upload certificate details will change and you need to rewrite SHA-1 etc. certificate details in respective places.

2) You provided **debug** key store / SHA-1 certificate details **instead of RELEASE** certificate details

3) error while generating certificates.

### **Solution**

1)  Go to [google play console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)

Relese management -> App signing

then you can see two types of certificate

1- Upload certificate ( your app certificate provided when generating signed apk)

2- App signing certificate ( because you enabled Google Play App Signing, so they provided new certificate details for your published apk)

> you need to change uploaded certificate details with new details
>   provided by google play where ever you used it before. such as
>   Integrating google sign in (change SHA-1 of [OAuth client](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)),
>   facebook login (change [key Hash](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)  (generate key hash using SHA-1
>   use this [link](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)  or copy the key hash provided by facebook login
>   error screen), [firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/) etc.

2) provide release SHA-1 / keyHash

[create](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) / use Keystore details of signed apk.

using command prompt:

google / firebase SHA-1 :

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

facebook  release key hash:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <user alias name> -keystore < keystore path> | <openssl-path> sha1 -binary | <openssl-path> base64
```

if asked for password enter your signed apk keystore password.

Answer (score 8):

If someone is not able to solve this issue then just open **Setup > app integrity**
in the console and then copy the SHA1 and paste in your firebase console.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

To add on existing responses, once you have the newly created SHA1:

Goto https://console.firebase.google.com:

1. Select project
2. Project Overview
3. Project Settings
4. **ADD FINGERPRINT** - enter SHA1 to Certificate fingerprint
5. Save

Answer (score 3):

In case of anyone facing this issue after Aug 2020. New SHA1 can be found at Setup->App Signing on your play console.
Everything else is the same as @PrinkalKumar as answered.

Answer (score 3):

in new version of the google console:

**Setup > app integrity**

Answer (score 3):

All answers specify either an outdated version of the Play console, or don't specify how to do it in the Firebase console.

So here goes my answer :

1. Get your SHA in your Google console by navigating to Release > Setup > App integrity in the menu, then clicking "App signing" tab. Copy the SHA-1.

[image]

2. In your Firebase console, go to Project settings > General tab. At the very bottom of the page, click "Add fingerprint". Paste the previously copied SHA-1 and save.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you enabled "Google Play App Signing" when publishing your app, you are now probably dealing with two fingerprints:

The one coming from your local keystore (keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-production-keystore -list -v), known as the "upload cert".

The new one generated by Google when you enabled Signing (the "signing certificate").

The conflict with this situation, is that you may end up with two OAuth 2.0 client IDs:

- The one that you created before publishing your app (and before enabling google signing), which is indeed the "right" one.
- A NEW one created by Google when you enabled Google Signing.

You can verify this fact from: Google Play Console -> Games Services -> Select your App -> Games Details -> API Console project -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 client IDs

**SOLUTION**

In order for Google Sign-in (and all related Games Services features) to work, I had to correct the fingerprint for my pre-existing OAuth2 Client ID (the one that I created before publishing my app).

1. Look for the "right" OAuth 2.0 client ID: Google Play Console -> Games Services -> Select your App -> Linked Apps --> Select your App --> Take note of the "OAuth2 Client ID" at the bottom.
2. Look for the "Signing" certificate: Google Play Console -> Games Services -> Select your App -> Game Details -> API Console project -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 client IDs --> "Android client for XXXXXX (auto created by Google Service)" --> Take note of the value (xx:xx:xx:etc....) Comment: In order to reuse this value in my other OAuth 2.0 client ID, I had to replace it with some dummy number. Otherwise, you will get error: "Certificate already used in some other project".
3. Go to your pre-existing OAuth2 Client ID: Google Play Console -> Games Services -> Select your App -> Games Details -> API Console project -> Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 client IDs --> Select "OAuth 2.0 client ID" from step 1. Update certificate value with the one from step 2.

This solved my issue. Multiplayer is working perfectly in my app (Match4App).

Answer (score 1):

Update SHA-1 Key in Firebase project setting

[image]

Also check your google cloud project api key setting and also add SHA-1 Key credentials if you have Key restrictions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Beside adding SHA-1 key to Firebase as described many times above, I needed to add this SHA-1 key to my Google Cloud API as a OAuth Client. After that, everything is working as expected

Answer (score -1):

just goto the google **play console > liked account and link your firebase project**. Now it works fine!