# Firebase Authentication is not working after signed APK generation (Google sign in)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am facing a problem with firebase authentication ( Google sign in)
It is running fine when I was testing but after generating signed APK and I installed it manually it's not working, for cross check , I have checked again it working when I am debugging..but in signed APK authentication not working.
Please tell me why its happening..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the SHA1 of the production certificate in Fireabase.
[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40864684/5940374)

Comment: For my case, I added all SHA1 and when I generate a signed .apk and install on the phone, everything works fine but when I published a signed .aab bundle, an error comes "This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console" Kindly advise me, this has taken me over 4 days but no success.

Answer (score 1):

You are having fingerprint certificate in console, but its only for debugging purposes, for signed apk you need a **production fingerprint certificate**, and you can get one by

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.25\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore c:\you_key_here.key
```

Answer (score -2):

It's simple, download (`KeyStore Explorer 5.3.2`) and open your `.jks` file using KeyStore Explorer it will ask for a password, enter your password that you entered at the time of generating signed apk. Then once it gets opened click on entry name there you will see Fingerprint SHA-1 key like `(10:02:A6:3E:A9:68:83:FE:F2:66:6F:F8:C4:9D:FF:3C:C2:EA:76:96)` this is fake SHA-1 ok, [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HglLn.jpg)

link : https://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html