# Google Sign In is not working after placing my app to playstore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have already put the debug and release SHA1 to my firebase project and downloaded the latest google-services.json file and placed it in my app.
now when I release my signed APK it is working fine on devices if I copy paste the APK and install it manually, but when I am downloading the APK from play store the google sign in is not working.

Everything is working fine before submitting APK to the playstore, but after submitting to the play store my app is not working as it fails to login to google.

I don't know what is the problem please help me.

Comment: In the last step before releasing the signature apk, which "Signature Versions" did you choose? I have used the v1 and it does work, didn't want to select the new signature version because I was afraid of this, I was expecting to do some testing before

Comment: i selected both the signature versions......does it make a difference because the signed apk is working fine before going to play store.

Comment: For what I read in the doc it should, because the version 2 is more secretivy, better encriptation, since I havent test it I dont know if that affect the sha1 associated to the signature, can you try with version 1 and see if thar fix it?

Comment: hey !!! try thiis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store/44330035#44330035