# FirebaseAuthException Error code: ERROR_APP_NOT_AUTHORIZED

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having an issue with Firebase Phone Auth in a Cordova Android app. The Auth works fine if I deploy the release (signed) version onto my phone via command line, but when I download the same apk from the Play Store I get this error:

unknown error verifying number Error instance: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException Error code: ERROR_APP_NOT_AUTHORIZED

The only difference between working and not working is install from command line:

```
sudo cordova build android --release -- --keystore=<keystorepath> --storePassword=<storepassword> --alias=scrib-android --password=<aliaspassword> --gradleArg=-PcdvVersionCode=<versioncode>
```

vs downloading from Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is addressed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330035/8692150

Basically, after you upload the apk to Google Play, they create an additional "App Signing" SHA-1 that needs to also be added to your Firebase console settings.