# Google login on release apk not working for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

I've created an Android app that uses the Google API for login feature. I've created a signed release apk for same. This apk runs fine when I install it directly to my phone, but Play published app for same doesn't move ahead with login. It allows me to select available account on device, but nothing happens after selection.

Please note that I've created google-services.json file using release SHA1

I'm using Android Studio 3.1, google play services 9.0.0 on Android 6 and later

Comment: I think that you should try debugging.

Comment: Does the SHA1 and package name of your release apk match those found at https://console.cloud.google.com

Comment: Even on debugging, I cannot find any error.

Yes, both are same on apk and console

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store   Check this Answer.

Comment: @kevanaghera, already did it

Comment: U try Second One Answer of the Question?

Comment: Thanks @kevanaghera. I did not notice that. It worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: @SBhaskar  Welcome its My Pleasure..

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store/44330035#44330035