# Firebase Authentication Fails Only on release Version of Android App

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, google-play-console

I've updated my Kotlin Android app, which uses Firebase Auth, Database, and Storage, increasing targetSdkVersion and dependencies to current versions. While everything operates as expected when deployed from Android Studio, downloading the app from the Play Store, or generating signed APK and deploying manually, results in all sign-in methods failing - despite working previously.

Discussions on Stack Overflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439480/firebase-google-authentication-not-working-in-release-mode/50868434#50868434), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360590/firebase-authentication-works-only-on-debug-version), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664680/google-authentication-is-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store)), suggest issues often stem from incorrect SHA certificate fingerprints, particularly the mix-up between the upload and the App Signing key from Google Play Console. My Firebase project, however, already includes both SHA-1 & SHA-256 of the App Signing key. Temporarily removing these fingerprints confirmed their significance by altering app behavior, for example: OTPs for phone sign-ins are received only while fingerprints are set (but sign-in fails).

Thus, I'm at a loss for what could be causing the sign-in methods to fail only in the signed version, and how to investigate it, as the problem does not occur in a debuggable version. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can offer insights into potential causes and solutions?

**AuthUI screen behavior for clicking each Auth provider in release versions:**

- **Google**: The app freezes on the AuthUI screen with a progress bar showing indefinitely.
- **Twitter**: Successfully opens the browser for authentication and indicates success, but causes the app to close upon redirection back.
- **Email**: No email is received.
- **Phone**: Upon receiving the OTP, the 'Phone Number' field turns red, displaying an "An unknown error occurred." message.

**Google Smart lock pop-up behavior in different versions:**

- **Debug version**: Shows Gmail based account options with their current profile photo set in the app (saved in Firebase).
- **Local signed APK**: Pop-up does not show at all.
- **Play Store version**: Shows Gmail based account options with no photos.

Comment: *downloading the app from the Play Store results in all sign-in methods failing*. What the error message that you get?

Comment: @AlexMamo Depends on the auth provider selected in the AuthUI screen - most do not give an error message. I edited the question to include behavior of each provider.

Comment: Does release version builded localy behave same way as the one from store?

Comment: @KarolKulbaka Generating Signed APK and deploying result in same as Play Store version, with a slight difference: here 'Google Smart Lock' pop-up does not show. Is there a way to debug this version?

Comment: @OmerLevy Yes, you can set debug flag for release build but you shouldn't do that. As far as you build this version locally you can just add some `println()` instructions to your code (using logger won't work if you setup it properly). First make sure that you add (at least temporally) SHA fingerprint from your keystore to firebase.

Comment: @KarolKulbaka why not set the debug flag temporarily? Will it change anything (while of course not uploading it to Play Store)? I have all 3 keys set in firebase (debug, keystore/upload & app signing from play console)

Comment: You can try with debug flag first, but if it work it will mean nothing

Comment: @KarolKulbaka I tried and it does not work, which is good as it gives me a way to debug it :) I now need to debug into the com.firebase.ui.auth library to find out where does it fail.