# Firebase Phone Auth not working in release build

Tags: android, firebase

The OTP verification works properly for debug build. I have also added SHA key in firebase console for release version. But Phone Auth doesn't work when I generate signed apk and upload it to play store.
Should I retain both debug SHA keys and release keys after I upload the app to production on play store?
Is Google App Signing compulsory for using a firebase app on production?

Comment: check your log, there might have some information

Comment: [Google sign in not working after publishing in play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store)

Comment: The issue is already answered here hope that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google sign in not working after publishing in play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If this is the issue occurring on the app uploaded to play store, then below can be a feasible solution.

**Steps**

1. Go to play console and select your app.
2. Under release management, go to app signing.
3. Find SHA-1 certificate and copy it.
4. Go to firebase console and select your app.
5. Go to project settings and add this SHA-1 certificate.

You are ready to rock again.

Comment: What issue are you facing still? @salvishahzad

Comment: This is now under Setup -> App Integrity

Comment: so the app should be publish first in order to use release version?

Comment: after wasting 4 hours, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add SHA-1 certificates. And if they are already added and you still face this problem (as in my case).
Add SHA-256 as well and it works!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to play console and select your app.
2. Go to Dashboards and under Setup, click on App Integrity.
3. Copy SHA-1 certificate and SHA-256 certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your firbase settings.  Authentication section - settings

Under authorised domains , add ur domain name in which ur app is hosted . Used only domain name , omit www