# Firebase Phone Auth not working in APK Release mode

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, apk, flutter-dependencies

I read following two questions but none of these are solution to my problem:

1. [Firebase Phone Auth not working in release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034419/firebase-phone-auth-not-working-in-release-build)
2. [Firebase Authentication not working in Signed APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864684/firebase-authentication-not-working-in-signed-apk)

Solution mentioned in both of these questions says that I need to copy SHA-1 from Play console and place it in Firebase console SHA-1 for my app. Problem is `My app is not on play store, I just signed it and build  the apks` as we normally do for apk.relase. And I also updated `firebase_auth` and `firebase_core` dependencies to latest version.

Below is my code for phone auth:

```
  verificationCompleted() {
    return (AuthCredential credential) async {
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((AuthResult value) {
        if (value.user != null) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => AddContacts(
                        user: value.user,
                      )));
        }
      });
    };
  }

  verificationFailed() {
    return (AuthException exception) {
      Toast.show('Verification Failed: ${exception.code}', context,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          duration: 3,
          backgroundRadius: 5,
          gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
    };
  }

  codeSent() {
    return (String verificationID, [int forceResendingToken]) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
              title: Text('Enter 6-Digit Code'),
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025),
                    controller: _controllerCode,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    maxLength: 6,
                    cursorColor: Colors.black,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorText: validateCode(_controllerCode.text),
                      hintText: 'Enter Code',
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.info,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Wait for Automatic Detection!',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Sogoe',
                            color: Colors.red,
                            fontSize:
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.017),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.06,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .05),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                      child: Text(
                        "Confirm",
                      ),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Colors.lightBlue,
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          _controllerCode.text.isEmpty
                              ? codeValidate = true
                              : codeValidate = false;
                        });
                        _auth.currentUser().then((user) {
                          if (user != null) {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => AddContacts(
                                          user: user,
                                        )));
                          } else {
                            _verifyCode();
                          }
                        });
                        _controllerCode.clear();
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
      _verificationId = verificationID;
    };
  }

  codeAutoRetrievalTimeout() {
    return (String verificationID) {
      _verificationId = verificationID;
    };
  }

  Future<void> _verifyPhoneNumber(String phone) async {
    _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phone,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted(),
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed(),
      codeSent: codeSent(),
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout(),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _verifyCode() async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: _verificationId, smsCode: _controllerCode.text);
    final FirebaseUser user =
        (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
    if (user != null) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AddContacts(
                    user: user,
                  )));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you add the SHA of your release apk to firebase?

Comment: @JideGuru yes, I did and the solution is posted below SHA-1 is separate for debug and release mode :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution

Yes I added SHA-1 Key but I came to know that SHA-1 for debug and release mode are separate and this [answer is solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)

Answer (score 4):

ADD YOUR PLAYSTORE SIGNING KEY CERTIFICATES TO FIREBASE SHA1 AND SHA256 CERTIFICATES.

 you'll find the key certificates in

**googele play console > under release  - setup > app integrity > App signing key certificate**
[image]