# Firebase Phone Auth on Android APK Release Version

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I tried to release an APK that is using Firebase Phone Auth on Google Play Store.
Everything works just fine on DEBUG and PROFILE mode.
But when I put it on RELEASE mode on play store here comes the problem:

[image: Figure 1]

What you see above is the log generated by my APK showing that it fails immediately when method `verifyPhoneNumber()` called. It only gives message `[firebase_auth/null] null` without any further explanation.

I already tried all answer in the following threads:

- [Firebase Phone Auth not working in APK Release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384384/firebase-phone-auth-not-working-in-apk-release-mode)
- [Firebase Phone Auth not working in release build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034419/firebase-phone-auth-not-working-in-release-build)
- [Firebase Authentication Not working in signed APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864684/firebase-authentication-not-working-in-signed-apk)
- [SHA-1 fingerprint of keystore certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727912/sha-1-fingerprint-of-keystore-certificate)

And unfortunately none of those solve my problem.

For your information, here's my flutter doctor and part of pubspec yaml.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

pubspec.yaml

```
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  firebase_analytics: ^6.3.0
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

Please masters help me!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a week of trying to figure this out, I finally got the solution.

In a brief conclusion: **IT IS ABOUT THE SHA-1 FINGERPRINT**.

Here's the solution:

1. So I got the SHA-1 fingerprint from the Google Play Console (Select your app >> Release >> Setup >> App Integrity | **App signing key certificate**).
2. Copy this SHA-1 fingerprint to your Firebase Project (Project Settings >> General | Your apps | SHA certificate fingerprints | **Add fingerprints**).
3. Go to the Google Cloud Platform >> API & Services >> Credentials >> API Keys. In my case, I restrict my API key for this specific app, thus I set the package ID and SHA-1 fingerprint. This what makes the `[firebase_auth null] null` happen. I forgot to put the SHA-1 fingerprint from step 1 for the restriction as well. When I added it, everything solved.

That is all, and voila.. my app works like a charm!
Hope this helps you if you get in here by a chance.
Don't forget to vote up! :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Add your Play store 'APP' SH1 AND SH256 into  your JSON file of firebase