# Android App Error when uploaded to Play Store , Before Uploading, tested everything was fine

Tags: java, android, firebase

Android App Error when uploaded to Play Store, Before Uploading, tested everything was fine.
Now my app is got published, and it's not opening, while opening getting a pop-up that saying "your app is closing" or close app now"
and I am taled to one developer and he sends me this(attached). and I have checked my firebase console everything was right, there android play store error:

```
W/Firebase-Installations: Error when communicating with the Firebase Installations server API. HTTP response: [403 Forbidden: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request from this Android client application com.zarza.mart are blocked.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API key",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/608839543771/apiui/credential"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase options used while communicating with Firebase server APIs: AIzaSyC_8qaCRic20001A--6WeoNGTRpBqKyJh0, zarzamart-b5f96,
E/Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of text please. Instead post the actual text of the error message. When you do, you can also search for the error message - as this one has almost certainly been asked before. If I recall correctly, the fix is to redownload your `google-services.json` and update in your app.

Comment: You've not updated the new sha1 key in Firebase console of the app uploaded to play store. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330035/8244632). This happens because app's sha1 key changes as Google applies its signing key to every app when uploaded to play store.

Comment: I am tried still, i cant open my app, it's closing automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try reconnect your app on firebase re downloading json file.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step2]