# Expo Google auth not working when published on Google Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, expo, sha1, google-play-console

I recently released my app on Google Play Store (internal test and internal app sharing) and soon found out that google auth does not work when I get the app through Google play store.

After spending hours on this issue, I found out that Google Play Store generates a new SHA-1 certificate (app signing key certificate) and that I need to save it on my firebase android app (which I did). I followed this instruction ([Google sign in not working after publishing in play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store)).

I also downloaded google-services.json file from firebase and recompiled the app with it. However, Google auth is still not working.

At this point, I think the problem has to do with release and debug SHA keys but I really can’t find any information about them in Expo environment. Am I supposed to create debug / release keys using Android Studio and add them to my app somehow?

I’ve been struggling with this issue for a week, and I'm very desperate for a solution. Please help!

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10/51360406) might help.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks so much for the advise Alex. My only question about that is do you know how to get the debug and release keys in Expo?

Comment: There are some links there with the infomation, have you checked them?

Comment: @AlexMamo Please correct me if I'm wrong - seems like expo automatically generates the debug key (which is the same as the upload key in Google Play store) for me, but I need to manually generate the release key using the terminal commands or Android Studio. This file is in .jks format, so I'll end up with two .jks files in my app. Then, I need to add the fingerprints in Firebase console along with the Google App signing certificate (so 3 total). I'm mostly confused about where to place the file that contains the release key.